# Can't walk dependency graph - browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, browserify

Using Browserify to bypass the 'require' issue.

Have these lines in my code:

```
let CryptoJS = require('node:crypto')
const util = require('util');
var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
```

When I try to bundle the file with Browserify I get:

*Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory....
...OpsPrime\Project Chimera\Netsuite SOAP\node:crypto*

I have looked at the solutions on here already, didn't work.

Tried changing node:crypto to just crypto and it did run, but my understanding is the 'crypto' module is depreciated and shouldn't be used, and actually I just encountered further issues.

So I have gone back to using node:crypto but Browserify can't find it for some reason.

Thank you.

Comment: The 'node:crypto' module is not a standard Node.js module and is likely a custom module or a typo in your code. The built-in 'crypto' module in Node.js should be used without the 'node:' prefix, and it is not deprecated.